# Unreferenced Thread object dispose

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispose

If i use thread like this:

```
void foo()
{
new Thread().Start();
}
```

since the Thread object is not referenced, will it be  disposed by GC before the designated work is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread should stay alive until its method(s) return.

Check out: [What prevents a Thread in C# from being Collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81730/what-prevents-a-thread-in-c-from-being-collected)

Comment: @Benny I believe so, but once the thread has done all the work it needs to do it should be handled by the GC

Answer (score 2):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

> It is not necessary to retain a
>   reference to a Thread object once you
>   have started the thread. The thread
>   continues to execute until the thread
>   procedure is complete.

The System.Threading.Thread class is really just there for bookkeeping/management. It isn't the actual mechanism that creates/maintains threads. That's managed by the runtime and is CLI implementation specific (for example, the Mono implementation may differ dramatically in thread management.)