# Does a Thread stop itself once it's function scope is over?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(threadFunction));

public void threadFunction() {
 // Run a finite code
 ...
}
```

Question is: will `myThread` get disposed once `threadFunction()` is over?

Comment: Eventually; when the function completes, the Thread state is set to `Stopped` and it will eventually be garbage collected. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81730/what-prevents-a-thread-in-c-sharp-from-being-collected

Comment: Yes, your thread will automatically disposed when complete its execution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Threads don't need to be disposed. The `Thread` class does not implement `IDisposable` and it does not have a `Dispose` method.

When your thread completes you don't need to do anything special to clean up.

Answer (score 2):

YES.. the thread will stop and will be disposed once the function returns..
to hold the thread you will have to do something like

```
while(true){}
```

Alternatively if you dont want your thread to be disposed because creating a new thread consumes resources
you should use a `ThreadPool` there is a class with the same name in .Net. 
so every time you need a thread it will be fetched from the thread pool and utilized