# Thread.Abort() and delay after finally

Tags: c#, multithreading, abort, finally

When Thread.Abort() is called, and that thread is executing finally block, then thread won't abort until finally block is finished. But, as i see, ThreadAbortException is generated not right after the end of finally block, but after some delay:

```
private static volatile int val1 = 0;

public static void Func1()
{
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
    //Func2();

    while (true)
        val1++;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var thread = new Thread(Func1);
    thread.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    thread.Abort();
    thread.Join();

    Console.WriteLine(val1);  // val1 is non-zero!
}
```

In this example, **val1** at the end of Main() will be non-zero. Why does it happen?

If i uncomment call to Func2() (Func2 is any method, possibly empty), output for **val1** will show "0". Why does adding of method affect point of thread abortion?

Comment: Interesting question, however in release mode without the debugger attached I can get a Non-zero number for `val1` too `Func2()` uncommented with a Empty function. With the debugger attached in release or in Debug with our without the debugger all give me 0.

Comment: `Thread.Abort` is **bad**, very **bad**.  It **will** leave your application in an unpredictable state, and you won't be able to rely on the common assumptions about program behavior after using it.  You should [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort) calling it at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it could be usefull to surround the increment with a `lock`. The lock controlls the access on that member. The `Abort` method just notify the thread "Hey, you can stop now" but it does not kill the Thread. So the thread can be alive for a few moments after the `Abort`. Accessing the `lock` the thread checks if it got aborted and kills it self if needed.

Here is your example code edited

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static volatile int val1 = 0;
        static Object Locker = new Object();

        public static void Func1()
        {
            try
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            //Func2();

            while (true)
            {
                //Lock the access to the member
                lock (Locker)
                    val1++;
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var thread = new Thread(Func1);
            thread.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Not needed. Just to make sure
            lock (Locker)
            {
                thread.Abort();
                thread.Join();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(val1);  // val1 is non-zero!
                                      // Now it is zero
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for late answer

Comment: `Thread.Abort` can abort a thread in the middle of a locked region.  If this happens, **it will not release the lock**.  This is extremely dangerous advice.

Comment: It will release the lock, cause the release of a lock is internal in a finally block and finally blocks will always executed if the thread aborts in one situation with finally, as the thread actually get kileld cause of a ThreadAbortException.
You also could just handle that exception instead. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18002756/8939287)

Comment: That isn't always true.  If the thread aborts *during* the finally block, it can skip releasing the lock.  See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort), with the some of the people that actually designed C# and .NET.