# Marshal.DestroyStructure vs Marshal.FreeHGlobal in .Net

Tags: .net, marshalling, dispose, unmanaged, finalizer

I have a managed .Net class that creates unmanaged resources that I need to ensure are cleaned up properly.

I have a sequential struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct FooBar { ... }
```

Then in the constructor I have:

```
// Allocate the memory
var fb = new FooBar(...);
int length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FooBar));
this.pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(fb, this.pointer, false);

// Then I use this.pointer in extern calls
```

Then in my `~Finaliser`/`Dispose` methods do I use `Marshal.DestroyStructure` or `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` or both (and if so in what order) to endure I don't leak the memory?

Bonus questions:

- Does my `IDisposable` class need to inherit `CriticalFinalizerObject` to ensure that the cleanup is always called?
- Is there a `Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles` class I could use here to wrap the dangerous unmanaged memory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both. The `Marshal.DestroyStructure` will free the "content" of the `FooBar`, while `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` will free the "container". Clearly first you free the content, then the container. So first `Marshal.DestroyStructure` then `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`.

I don't think `CriticalFinalizerObject` is in any way related to marshaling `struct`, and a `struct` can't inherit from anything, so the response is no to the first question.

Comment: Wouldn't a single call to `FreeHGlobal` have the same effect since it frees the memory that contains the structure, therefore implicitly destroying the structure as well?

Comment: @aevitas Let's say that the C# struct is `struct FooBar { public string str; }`... The `Marshal.StructureToPtr` will allocate a separate memory for marshaling the `str` (because it will marshal the struct to a C `struct FooBar { char* str; }`... That memory will be freed by `Marshal.DestroyStructure` (and is what I called the "content"). If there is no data that require special marshaling (so for example `struct FooBar { public int value; }`) then `Marshal.DestroyStructure` can be skipped.

Comment: Cheers - I've added a clarification on the `CriticalFinalizerObject`. My concern is that if the .Net process is killed (in Process Explorer, for instance) the unmanaged allocation will leak.

Comment: @Keith Memory can't be leaked on process death. All the memory allocated is recovered by the OS. It is like the cornerstone of OS handling of memory.

Comment: @Keith Note that if your problem is `Thread.Abort`, that is a different thing... `CriticalFinalizerObject` will be executed in case of `Thread.Abort`... But if that is your problem, you'll have to subclass the `SafeHandle` class (that is a `CriticalFinalizerObject`)

Comment: @Keith Note that `finally` blocks will be executed on `Thread.Abort` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18002756/613130)), so you don't need a CFO for that... Without having tested it, from what I know, the `AppDomain.Unload` throws some `ThreadAbortException` around, so it should be like `Thread.Abort`, so the `finally` blocks will probably be executed.

Comment: @xanatos let's say `struct FooBar { public string str; }`. Isn't `FreeHGlobal` enough to release the memeory? If the container is released, shoudn't the content be considerred as released?

Comment: @joe No, because `FreeHGlobal` doesn't know that the `IntPtr` that it receives is a `FooBar`, so it can't free the `str`. Memory allocalted with `AllocHGlobal` is called "unmanaged memory" for a reason: the GC doesn't manage it.