# Do I need to call Marshal.DestroyStructure when marshalling structures containing ByValTStr strings

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, marshalling

I am doing some manual marshaling for interop from C#/.NET to unmanaged DLLs.

Consider the following struct:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private struct LockInfo
{
    ushort lockVersion;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string lockName;
}
```

I marshal this to unmanaged memory:

```cs
var lockInfo = new LockInfo();
var lockInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(lockInfo));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(lockInfo, lockInfoPtr, false);
```

Once I'm done with it, do I need to call `Marshal.DestroyStructure` on `lockInfoPtr`?

I am aware of the need to call `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`, but prior to that, is `Marshal.DestroyStructure` actually required in this case?

I have found it very difficult to understand Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.destroystructure) around this. Google searching hasn't helped, possibly because I just don't quite understand marshalling properly yet (but I am learning).

**Similar questions...**

I have reviewed the similar question "[Marshal.DestroyStructure vs Marshal.FreeHGlobal in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020249/marshal-destroystructure-vs-marshal-freehglobal-in-net)" but this question does not address the issue of the *content* a struct should contain that would require the use of `DestroyStructure`. My limited understanding is that `DestroyStructure` does not always need to be called, only when the structure contains certain kinds of fields. In my case I am unsure if a string, being marshalled as ByValTStr, requires the use of `DestroyStructure`.

Comment: @CoolBots Unfortunately no. I have updated my question with a reference to that question and explanation.

Comment: I retracted my vote to close as duplicate, based on your explanation. My understanding is you'd need to call `Marshal.DestroyStructure` due to marshaling a `string`, which is a reference type. I am not 100% on that though; I also am not sure if calling this method can be detrimental in cases where it's not needed to be called. I'll leave the task of actually posting an answer to someone better versed in the matter. I do agree with you the documentation is not entirely clear.

Comment: You may find these tests useful (part 1 to 3): [Passing a Pointer to a Structure from C# to C++ Part 1](https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/passing-a-pointer-to-a-structure-from-c-to-c-part-1/). After Part 2, you may be induced to think that you need to call that method. Finish part 3 (take note of what types are used: now you need to have a clear idea of the difference between blittable and non-blittable types in this context and why SafeArrays and COM BSTR are mentioned). Possibly, make a test yourself (you may get to a different conclusion after, but then you know why).

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for the link - how did I not find this already. Pretty much everything I need to know is there. I will study it thoroughly and, if after a couple days this question remains unanswered, I will offer an answer based on my learnings.

Comment: ByValTStr + SizeConst is preallocated (part of the memory pointed by lockInfoPtr), so no, you don't need to call Marshal.DestroyStructure. In fact this method is (or should be) rarely used, it depends on your native side, or how you want to cooperate between managed and native. When in doubt, run this in a loop, call GC.Collect sometimes, and check if the memory (Perfmon's private bytes) is stable over time.

Comment: @SimonMourier Great comment. Goes against my intuition. But you are right - `Marshal.DestroyStructure` is not required in this case. As you suggested, I did extensive loop testing (left it going for a few hours) and private memory use was rock stable so clearly no leaking. Do you want to answer the question for credit? Otherwise I'll sort out an answer and reference your comment in it.

Comment: @MichalCihelka - you can do it :-)

Comment: @SimonMourier Done. I've tried to word things in a way that someone new to custom marshaling (like myself) would be able to understand. If you spot something in my answer that's not right do let me know so I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marshaling is complex stuff and a full answer could fill a whole chapter in a book, which of course is not appropriate here. So, in a very succinct nutshell:

Normally, when calling native functions from managed code, .NET marshals strings and arrays to native **BSTR** strings and **SafeArray** arrays.

To accomplish this, the marshaler calls [`SysAllocString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysallocstring) and [`SafeArrayCreate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraycreate) respectively.

At some point, when these native-side strings and arrays are no longer needed, the marshaler will call [`SysFreeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysfreestring) and [`SafeArrayDestroy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraydestroy) respectively to free memory.

If you take over .NET's automatic marshaling, and call methods like [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr) to manually marshal a structure, *you* become responsible for freeing/destroying those native-side BSTRs and SafeArrays. That's exactly what [`Marshal.DestroyStructure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.destroystructure) is for.

However...

By prepending the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]` attribute to your string field, you instructed the marshaler to *not* marshal the string to a BSTR string, but rather to allocate a fixed-length character array within the native-side structure itself.

That being the case, there is no need to call `Marshal.DestroyStructure` because there is no BSTR string to free. Of course you will still need to call `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`, I see you are aware of that.

*Credit to **@SimonMourier** for his comment that made it all click.*