# Why isn't ThreadAbortException automatically rethrown if raised after an asynchronous await?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, try-catch, threadabortexception

While investigating [an issue with `finally`, `await`, and ThreadAbortException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215240/why-is-a-finally-block-sometimes-not-executed-on-threadabortexception-if-it-co), I came another quirk. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the **catch** block.

But consider this console program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Run(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Run(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task Run(bool yield)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(yield ? "With yielding" : "Without yielding");
        try
        {
            try { await Abort(yield); }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    ThreadAbortException caught");
            } // <-- ThreadAbortException should be automatically rethrown here
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    Rethrown ThreadAbortException caught");
            Thread.ResetAbort();
        }
    }

    static async Task Abort(bool yield)
    {
        if (yield)
            await Task.Yield();
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
    }
}
```

When I compile this in Visual Studio 2015, the output is:

```
Without yielding
    ThreadAbortException caught
    Rethrown ThreadAbortException caught
With yielding
    ThreadAbortException caught
```

So a ThreadAbortException raised after `Task.Yield()` is no longer automatically rethrown by a `catch` block! Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it happens if you don't `await Task.Yield` is that the code is executed synchronously on the same thread as the caller so it's like not being `async` at all.

When you `await`, the continuation will be queued on a `ThreadPool` thread which is a managed thread and behaves differently.

Since internally is caught and re-thrown from a different thread than the current, it doesn't preserve it's nature of "**special application killing**" exception in the shifting logic.

In addition, if it was to re-throw it, you wouldn't even been able to `Thread.ResetAbort()` as it works on the current thread and will not act on the one that actually aborted.

**MSDN** documentation explains this, too [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/exceptions-in-managed-threads):

> If any of these exceptions are unhandled in threads created by the
>   common language runtime, the exception terminates the thread, but the
>   common language runtime does not allow the exception to proceed
>   further.
>
> If these exceptions are unhandled in the main thread, or in threads
>   that entered the runtime from unmanaged code, they proceed normally,
>   resulting in termination of the application.

My guess on the rationale behind this is: `ThreadAbortException` is re-thrown to avoid stubborn threads to try and stay alive when they shouldn't, but letting it flow and kill also other different threads would probably be quite a bad idea and cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Would these not be considered handled exceptions? Why not?

Comment: @JonathonChase If I understood your question (why catching re-throws if we're catching it!?) I can only imagine that is a legacy behaviour that used to kill the application if the main thread was aborted. The article above calls them `The common language runtime provides a backstop for certain unhandled exceptions that are used for controlling program flow` which is not entirely clear.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The documentation you referenced discussed the behavior of unhandled exceptions. My understanding is that these exceptions are handled by the catch statements.

Comment: You're right, it calls them `unhandled` exceptions, but it doesn't explain why it stays unhandled after catching it. This part of the documentation explains the special case in the *Remarks* section: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b50fdsz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: *"When this method is invoked on a thread, the system throws a ThreadAbortException in the thread to abort it. ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught by application code, but is re-thrown at the end of the catch block unless ResetAbort is called."* from the docs.

Comment: Which I think brings us back around to the crux of the question: why isn't the exception rethrown, or if it is, why is it not caught, if the catch contains an await statement?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, I think it's because it's on a different thread. It is re-thrown to avoid stubborn threads to try and stay alive when they shouldn't and unwind the call stack entirely, but letting it kill other threads would probably be quite bad.

Comment: @JonathonChase I think it is correct explanation. You can throw ThreadAbortException all day and it *will not* be automatically re-thrown as it is *not-so-special* when created any other way than `.Abort` (same as `throw new StackOverflowExcepction()` - which kills the process if raised due to actual SO). (Throwing ThreadAbort directly a bit tricky as there is no public constructor, but you can always - `throw (Exception)(typeof(ThreadAbortException).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance, null, CallingConventions.Any, new Type[0], null).Invoke(new object[0] {}));
`)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That makes sense, and would help explain why issuing a `throw;` in the inner catch would cause the `Thread.ResetAbort();` in the outer catch to fail with `Unable to reset abort because no abort was requested.` I'm guessing that by this point the thread has been dealt with by the CLR, which is why the re-throw isn't occurring on it's own.

Comment: I'd like to understand the details of how this happens, with citations to Reference Source if possible. For example, is this behavior defined by the thread pool, by the Task class, or by something else? Would this same behavior happen with SynchronizationContexts that don't use the thread pool?

Comment: @MichaelLiu with a SyncContext it will depend on the implementation. ASP.NET/WinForms/WPF dispatch the behaviour on the main UI thread, so I presume it could re-throw in that case (to test), but if you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for sure it will behave the same. By source you mean source code? Reference to the documentation is in the links I shared.

Comment: Don't take my word for it on the re-throw thing as there will still be switching... So the async code may still run on a `ThreadPool` thread and I don't know if switching back will keep the old behaviour.

Comment: By "Reference Source" I mean the [.NET Framework source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).