# Can a .NET thread be interrupted between a method returning and assigning its return value?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, threadabortexception

Is it theoretically possible that something will interrupt a .NET thread (e.g. a ThreadAbortException) between the return of a method and the assignment of its return value to a local?

For example, is this following code safe or is it possible that `myMutex.WaitOne()` acquires the mutex and returns `true`, but an exception is thrown before that value `true` is assigned to `mutexAcquired` and therefore the acquired mutex is not released?

```
bool mutexAcquired = false;
try
{
    mutexAcquired = myMutex.WaitOne(1000);
    if (!mutexAcquired)
       throw new Exception();
    // OK, do some stuff...
}
finally
{
    if (mutexAcquired)
        myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

If that is safe, then what about the following code?

```
if (!myMutex.WaitOne(1000))
   throw new Exception();

try
{
    // OK, do some stuff...
}
finally
{
    myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Again, is it possible for `myMutex.WaitOne()` to  return true, but for ThreadAbortException (or similar) to be thrown on the `if`, before the `try` block is entered?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002668/can-threadabortexception-skip-finally

Comment: In case of a call to the `Thread.Abort` (very bad practice) method in the middle of `myMutex.WaitOne()`, yes the mutex can be acquired and the boolean value not updated to true. And then the mutex is not released.

The second piece of code looks safer.

Comment: I don' know why I bother asking detailed questions on SO any more when I know people will just scan them for a few key words looking to close it as a duplicate as fast as possible. This question is not about finally blocks at all. Nor is it specifically about ThreadAbortException, that was just an example. The question is: "Can a .NET thread be interrupted between a method returning and assigning its return value?" If it is answered by one of the two linked questions then what is the answer - yes or no? Alright, I'll ask it again *without* providing example code for context.